# Trying to use onbeforeUnload and it is firing on every user action ... Why?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a small code snippet here, I want this code executed only when the user tries to close the window by pressing the "X" at the top. I want to capture their login credentials The issue is that no matter what action the user takes, pressing a button or pressing the button to submit, this code executes. What am I doing incorrectly? Thank you in advance for your help!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function ()  {
            <% Close_btn(); %>
        }
         </script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the submit button reloads the page, and that would be considered an "unload" !

Comment: If he presses a submit button and that makes your page reload, the onbeforeunload is supposed to fire. Afaik onbeforeunload gets fires everytime you navigate to a different url or refresh the page... so everytime the current content gets unloaded.

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong ... there's no way to reasonably detect just the 'x' button. You have to manage when to add the event etc. IE only add it if some credentials have been added instead of what it appears to be onload (IE always).

Comment: Thanks all ... I appreciate all of your comments, as usual!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jquery example, since I'm too lazy to turn it into pure js, but you should get the idea:

```
$('#login').on('click',function() { 
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {}; 
    return true; 
);
```

That way, when they do the other function, you first unset the unload, since you know it will fire anytime the unload happens, you just unset it when it will unload in a way where you don't want that action to happen.